# join order step by step in oracle

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have a trouble with below query.I want to join columns in step.
For example a.code first b.name1 if not match then join name2 etc.But i cant handle the query.

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE A 
LEFT JOIN TABLE B 
 ON A.CODE = B.NAME1
 OR A.CODE = B.NAME2
 OR UPPER(B.NAME3) = UPPER(A.NAME)
```

Thanks

edit
with sample below,
if TABLEB.CODE = TABLEA.NAME1 match then dont want to look  OR TABLEB.CODE = TABLEA.NAME2.
And if not matching any TABLEB.CODE = TABLEA.NAME1 then step by step match the columns on that order.

```
 WITH TABLEA AS (SELECT 13445  AS ID,'A'  AS  TYPE,'DFSF' AS NAME1 ,  'PCK' AS NAME2 FROM DUAL
                 UNION ALL 
                SELECT 13445  AS ID,'A'  AS  TYPE,'PCK' AS NAME1 ,  'PCK' AS NAME2 FROM DUAL),

      TABLEB AS (SELECT 56544  AS ID, 'PCK' AS  CODE,     'PCK' AS  FRST_NM FROM DUAL)
 SELECT * FROM TABLEA 
 LEFT JOIN TABLEB 
 ON TABLEB.CODE = TABLEA.NAME1
 OR TABLEB.CODE = TABLEA.NAME2
 OR UPPER(TABLEB.FRST_NM) = UPPER(TABLEA.NAME2)
```

Comment: GIve sample data and expected output

Comment: You joining table with self ?

Comment: Why does it matter which condition they match on - it won't affect the result? Or do you mean that for a given code from table B, you only want to find the single 'best' match for that code from table A? More data and expected results would still be useful too.

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "step by step" or "dont want to look OR TABLEB.CODE = TABLEA.NAME2." Perhaps you could illustrate with some sample results showing the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe your query will do what you want. There is no `step by step` in join conditions if you have already mentioned `OR`. So if either of the condition match, the rows will be matched. So if `A.CODE <> B.NAME1` but `A.CODE = B.NAME2`, they will match. If both are true, then also they will match. I create a CTE with sample data to see the output. It will return 3 rows for 3 matches.

```
    WITH TBL(SEQ,CODE,NAME,NAME1,NAME2,NAME3)  AS
    (
       SELECT 1,'A1','B','A1','D','E' FROM DUAL UNION ALL -- as A.CODE(A1)=B.NAME1, it will match
       SELECT 2, 'B2','B','D','B2','F' FROM DUAL UNION ALL --as A.CODE (B2) <> B.NAME1 , it will match for B.NAME2
       SELECT 3, 'G','H1','D','A','H1' FROM DUAL UNION ALL --match for UPPER(B.NAME3) = UPPER(A.NAME)
       SELECT 4,'P4','Q4','R4','S4','T4' FROM DUAL
    )
    SELECT * FROM TBL A 
    LEFT JOIN TBL B 
    ON (A.CODE = B.NAME1
      OR A.CODE = B.NAME2
      OR UPPER(B.NAME3) = UPPER(A.NAME)
        )
```

Column SEQ is just to see what rows are returning.

Output

```
+-----+------+------+-------+-------+-------+-------+--------+--------+---------+---------+---------+
| SEQ | CODE | NAME | NAME1 | NAME2 | NAME3 | SEQ_1 | CODE_1 | NAME_1 | NAME1_1 | NAME2_1 | NAME3_1 |
+-----+------+------+-------+-------+-------+-------+--------+--------+---------+---------+---------+
|   1 | A1   | B    | A1    | D     | E     |     1 | A1     | B      | A1      | D       | E       |
|   2 | B2   | B    | D     | B2    | F     |     2 | B2     | B      | D       | B2      | F       |
|   3 | G    | H1   | D     | A     | H1    |     3 | G      | H1     | D       | A       | H1      |
|   4 | P4   | Q4   | R4    | S4    | T4    |       |        |        |         |         |         |
+-----+------+------+-------+-------+-------+-------+--------+--------+---------+---------+---------+
```

Comment: So your expected output is just the 2 rows returned from your query?

Comment: no dear Utsav, i expected 1  row.Its like TABLEB.CODE = TABLEA.NAME1 if match then no need to look other join columns

Comment: LEFT JOIN TABLEB     
 ON TABLEB.CODE = TABLEA.NAME1   --first_match 
 OR TABLEB.CODE = TABLEA.NAME2   --if failed first match
 OR UPPER(TABLEB.FRST_NM) = UPPER(TABLEA.NAME2) -- if failed second match

Comment: I think you are not getting what I mentioned in the answer. If you are using `or` conditions, then if first condition dont match, it would automatically see if any of the other conditions are matching or not. If no conditions are matching, then it will not match them. I think you should give a more elaborate sample and also give your expected data.